# Google play Console Account

Tags: testing, console, publish, playback

Please I received a gig from someone and they need a Google play console account of like 7months old and already tested applications on them. My own account is recent.. please anybody that has an account of 7month old please let's connect

I have tried asking people around though, I felt this is the best place I would get a response